# Avoiding race conditions with Route53 upserts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I need to programatically update an `A` record that contains multiple `IPv4` entries.

The update is triggered whenever an EC2 instance starts/terminates.

The approach I had in mind was to `read` the current record, append the `IPv4` address, then `upsert` the new record to Route53. However, this leads to possible race conditions.

What's the best way to achieve this, to avoid race conditions?

(p.s. ELB is not an option -- I require DNS round-robin load balancing.)

Answer (score 1):

[Route53's multivalued answers](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-route-53-announces-support-for-multivalue-answers-in-response-to-dns-queries/) are the correct approach here.

Instead of having one `A` record, you create multiple `A` records (one for each IP) and discriminate them using a `SetIdentifier` that you specify when creating the record ([see API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-setidentifier)). The `SetIdentifier` can be anything you like, and the unique ID of the record effectively becomes `record_name:set_identifier`.

Route53 will automatically merge these records into a single record when responding to client requests (so it will return an `A` record containing the set of all IPs you specified as individual records).

This means you can atomically `upsert`/`delete` your individual IP addresses, avoiding the race-conditions you would face when attempting to update an `A` record containing multiple values.

---

As an aside, Route53 can optionally health-check each record, and only return healthy ones :)